# multi threaded rule engine with drools 7.4.1

Tags: drools, rule-engine, drools-kie-server

As per the documentation it says the multi threaded rule engine is introduced in Drools 7.0 and is experimental

***Is this still experimental in 7.4.1 or is it production worthy in latest release 7.4.1.***

[What is New and Noteworthy in Drools 7.0](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.4.1.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_multithreaded_rule_engine)

This feature is off by default, but it’s possible to create a parallel KieBase by enabling it via the KieBaseConfiguration as it follows:

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieBaseConfiguration kieBaseConf = ks.newKieBaseConfiguration();
kieBaseConf.setOption(MultithreadEvaluationOption.YES);
KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.newKieBase(kieBaseConf);
```

or alternatively through the system property:

```
drools.multithreadEvaluation = true
```

Regards

Saravanan

Comment: For faster response I suggest that you might ask this on the Drools User list.

Comment: Thanks got reply from the drools user list."
When we say it's experimental, we don't mean it might be buggy, more that it needs improving so that it's more generically useful. It's only useful in specialised use cases, that ensure there are large volumes of work in the rule matching space per insert, across enough rules."

Comment: Sounds like something from Pythia, the Delphian oracle, which always was intentionally unclear. I would reply, asking for clarification.